# How can I ignore dots in incoming email addresses with exim?

Tags: exim

If my users have usernames of the form `firstlast` within my `example.com` domain, is there a way to get exim to correctly deliver to them whatever the number of dots put into the address? This is a feature that Gmail has.

```
first.last@example.com
fir.stl.ast@example.com
f.i.r.s.t.l.a.s.t+label@example.com
```

are all delivered to `firstlast@example.com`, the last with its tag preserved for filtering.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to normalise outgoing email from these users to have the form of dots that they select (also a feature of Gmail) so that their mail will always appear to come from first.last@example.com if that's what they select.

Comment: See the various `local_part` settings of a router.  There is probably some way to do this.

Comment: Its a matter of `rewrite` mechanism. You can refer to the chapter 31 of `exim`' spec, there is few interesting examples there. Heavy regex voodoo it should be...

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know Google allows you to split your name just anywhere.  The following should allow the users to place any suffix they desire after their userid which is relatively commonly done.  Gmail seems to allow a plus sign instead of a dot.

```
dot_local:
  driver = accept
  domains = +local_domains
  local_part_suffix = .*
  check_local_user
  transport = LOCAL_DELIVERY
```

Exim should already lookup up outgoing email address aliases in `/etc/email-addresses`.  Either add the user's preferred address to this file, or build your own rewrite mechanism based on the existing rewrite rule.

To remove all dots from the address try replacing `local_part_suffix = .*` in the above router with `data = ${sg{$local_part}{[.]}{}}@$domain`.  This should attempt local deliver of the address with all dots removed.  This variation of one of my routers should also work.

```
gmail_local:
  debug_print       = "R: gmail_local for $local_part@$domain"
  driver            = redirect
  domains           = +local_domains
  data              = ${sg{$local_part}{[.]}{}}@$domain
```

If you want both functions I believe you will need to use `driver = redirect` in at least one router, or combine both functionalities into a single router.

Comment: Google simply strips any dots in the leading part for delivery - look at the first reason on this help page: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10313. You really can just put dots anywhere.

Comment: @IainHallam I've added a router definition that should do what you want.  The original option can be modified to add the '+.,..' functionality that Google allows.